# Multi-Byte UTF-8 in Arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, unicode, wchar

I have been having trouble working with 3-byte Unicode UTF-8 characters in arrays. When they are in char arrays I get multi-character character constant and implicit constant conversion warnings, but when I use wchar_t arrays, wcout returns nothing at all. Because of the nature of the project, it must be an array and not a string. Below is an example of what I've been trying to do.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    wchar_t testing[40];
    testing[0] = L'\u0B95';
    testing[1] = L'\u0BA3';
    testing[2] = L'\u0B82';
    testing[3] = L'\0';
    wcout << testing[0] << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Any suggestions? I'm working with OSX.

Comment: When you store them in `char` arrays, such a code point would take three `char`s. Multi-character character constants are an entirely different thing.

Comment: wstring are not utf8 (they are not necessarily UTF-16 nor UCS4). You don't know what encoding they are, so writing fixed values inide them is asking for trouble.

Comment: They don't have _any_ encoding. They are just some bytes.

Answer (score 4):

Since `'\u0B95'` requires 3 bytes, it is considered a *multicharacter literal*. A multicharacter literal has type `int` and an implementation-defined value. (Actually, [I don't think gcc is correct to do this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13547368/150634))

Putting the `L` prefix before the literal makes it have type `wchar_t` and has an implementation defined value (it maps to a value in the *execution wide-character set* which is an implementation defined superset of the *basic execution wide-character set*).

The C++11 standard provides us with some more Unicode aware types and literals. The additional types are `char16_t` and `char32_t`, whose values are the Unicode code-points that represent the character. They are analogous to UTF-16 and UTF-32 respectively.

Since you need character literals to store characters from the basic multilingual plane, you'll need a `char16_t` literal. This can be written as, for example, `u'\u0B95'`. You can therefore write your code as follows, with no warnings or errors:

```
char16_t testing[40];
testing[0] = u'\u0B95';
testing[1] = u'\u0BA3';
testing[2] = u'\u0B82';
testing[3] = u'\0';
```

Unfortunately, the I/O library does not play nicely with these new types.

If you do not truly require using character literals as above, you may make use of the new UTF-8 string literals:

```
const char* testing = u8"\u0B95\u0BA3\u0B82";
```

This will encode the characters as UTF-8.